# Record Audio via USB - RP 355 (Guitar Pedal)

Tags: drivers, usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just contacted Digitech's online support, but since they don't support Linux there are no official drivers for the RP 355.
I can load and save presets with gdigi, but as of now I can't figure out how to record audio via USB. The Pedal is actually listed in the pulse audio settings under "Input", but no sound level is registrated and subsequently recorded even if I'm strumming and everything.

Do I have to hit some record button on the pedal or is there some relatively simply tweak to install drivers in order to make the RP355 USB Recording work.
Regarding the first option I couldn't find anything in the official manual.

Any suggestions or experience with RP Pedals and Linux?

Comment: Does this device require a separate driver (not the built-in one) in Windows?

Comment: What I know is Digitech offers official windows drivers for download. But I have no information whether the plain OS would offer basic functionality anyways.

Comment: Are there any mixer controls in `alsamixer`? (Select the actual hardware device.)

Comment: As you can tell I'm not familiar with this stuff at all, but what I can say is:

Whether I run alsamixer with the pedal plugged in (when it also shows up at PulseAudio's input list) or not alsamixer lists the same three options S/PDIF , S/PDIF 1 & S/PDIF 2.Hope that is useful information

Comment: Press "S" or "F6" to select another sound card.

Comment: It does show up, but no "This sound device does not have any controls. "

Comment: Then it's possible that it needs some unknown vendor-specific commands to enable it.